# How to control your cwd when debugging .net core xUnit test in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core, xunit

VSCode 1.20.0 running Windows 10. Opened a folder containing an sln pointing to csproj, target framework netcoreapp2.0.

csproj for the xUnit test:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.5.0" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.3.1" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.3.1" />
```

Clicking on "Debug Test" link next to the test method launches debugging. The tests fails when trying to open a file. The file path in the test assumes the current working directory is ${workspaceFolder}/test. Unfortunately the cwd is closer to ${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/

launch.json:

```
"name":".NET Core Launch (console)"
"cwd":"${workspaceFolder}/test
```

It appears xUnit "Debug Test" link doesn't use the ".NET Core Launch (console) configuration. But what else?

How do I control the cwd for xUnit tests launched inside vscode by clicking the "Debug Test" link?